# Comment choisir entre "au ras" et "à ras"

Tags: prépositions

*Ras* le bol de ne pas savoir si un arbre doit être coupé [à ras de terre](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ras/66552) ou si cette question se trouve [au ras des paquerettes](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/13974/au-ras-des-paquerettes/).

J'ai l'impression qu'on peut remplir un verre [à ras bord](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_ras_bord) lorsqu'il est au **ras du sol** (ou alors dit-on **à ras le sol** ?)

Bref, y a-t'il une règle pour savoir s'il faut utiliser **à** ou **au** quand on utilise le mot **ras** ?

Comment: On peut autant dire "Au ras du sol" que "A ras le sol" il me semble...

Comment: @Random : de la même manière, "au ras du bord" me semble correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selon Jean Girodet, (*[Dictionnaire des pièges et difficultés de la langue française](http://www.langue-fr.net/Notice-Girodet-Bordas-des-difficultes)*) à l'exception de l'expression figée *à ras de terre*, les deux formes *à ras de* et *au ras de* sont correctes et admises, mais *au ras de* est la plus fréquente.

Un ngram confirme que *au ras de* est plus fréquent que *à ras de* :
[image: "au ras de" vs "à ras de"]

Mais une autre recherche montre que  *à ras de terre* n'est pas une expression si figée que ça, car même si bien moins fréquent, *au ras de terre* est aussi employé, et ce, depuis fort longtemps :
[image: au-a ras de terre]

Pour ce qui est de *à ras bord* et de *au ras bord*, *à ras bord* prédomine très largement, même si les deux se rencontrent :
[image: ras bord]

Il semble donc qu'effectivement il n'y ait pas de règle et le choix est personnel. Si ça peut faire pencher la balance d'un côté ou de l'autre, signalons que *au ras de*  est antérieur à *à ras de* :

> ... *au res de* (v. 1175) forme primitive pour *au ras de* (fin XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle concurrencé ensuite par *à ras de*, « très près de » notamment dans *à ras de bord* (1798), contracté en ***à ras bord*** (1893) ...

*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey.

En conclusion : la langue vit, vive la langue !

Comment: Merci pour la réponse ! Les ngram prennent-ils en compte les formes dérivées (utilisant un 'd' avec une apostrophe plutôt que 'de') ? Aussi je me demandais, d'où venaient-ils ?